# Resource doesnot contain definition for Menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

i am learning to build app using xamarin and i got error while creation options menu.
The code and metadata is pasted below.

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = MenuInflater;
    inflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.Options, menu);
    return true;
    //return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.action_refresh)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And the metadata is pasted below:

```
public partial class Menu
{

    // aapt resource value: 0x7F0C0000
    public const int Options = 2131492864;

    static Menu()
    {
        global::Android.Runtime.ResourceIdManager.UpdateIdValues();
    }
```

This is the second error while using Resource.Id.action_refresh, metadata of designer is pasted below:

```
public const int action_refresh = 2131230744;
```

This is the ouput:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: AndApp, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 1>C:\Users\simon\source\repos\AndApp\AndApp\MainActivity.cs(31,39,31,43): error CS0117: 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Menu' 1>C:\Users\simon\source\repos\AndApp\AndApp\MainActivity.cs(37,44,37,58): error CS0117: 'Resource.Id' does not contain a definition for 'action_refresh' ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need to use **Resource.Menu** , you need to create a **menu** folder below **Resources** folder.

[image]

Then create the **.xml** file inside it. Such as:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Then can used in **xxxActivity.cs**:

```
public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**Note**: When adding new element in **Resources**, you'd better clean project and rebuild it.Then can use the new element in code. If also show red underline of the resource element, you can ignore it to continue to build and run project. It will run successfully generally. Because sometimes Visual Studio can not update new element to code immediately.

Comment: I did that my XML file name is Options and folder name is menu just like u said

Comment: I also cleaned the solution

Comment: @AmazingPets Okey, Close the VS, and restart it to check whehter it works.

Comment: @AmazingPets And whether the first word of `menu` folder name is lowercase?

Comment: no still the same and the the options.xml is at the Resource.designer.cs and is invoked from there not the location of the folder.

Comment: @AmazingPets Could you share the screenshot of `menu` folder? And you can delete the content of `Resource.designer.cs`, then rebuild project to check whether it works.

Comment: It is the same as the answered by you only the XML file name is different my XML file is Options.xml

Comment: @AmazingPets Okey , sorry for having no other ideas about this. If you can share the sample project link here, I will check that in local site.